# Video recording when your neighbours are creating nuisance?

Tags: united-kingdom, recording

Is it illegal to make a video recording when your neighbours are creating nuisance in the back garden?

Comment: What is the city/state/country where are you located? Are the neighbors' activities viewable from a public street or otherwise public area? Or only viewable from private space, such as your yard?

Comment: I live in the UK. Since I live in a semi-detached house our back garden share the "wall". I can see/hear them from my window which faces the back garden.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is recording a neighbors yard legal in Colorado, USA?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/37326/is-recording-a-neighbors-yard-legal-in-colorado-usa)

Comment: Since th3 other question was specifically limited to Colorado in the uS, and this is for the UK where the laws are likely to be different, I do not think this is a duplicate, and should not be closed as such.

Answer (score -2):

Without knowing the laws in the UK, I would think it reasonable that you could film  your dog (or the like) in your backyard and any reasonable incidental recording could (not necessarily) be in compliance with UK law.  Best to check with the equivalent of a lawyer.

It would be interesting to hear the argument \ law against indoor filming from you window.